# Initializing and checking pointer and other auto variables in C

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

Should I initialize regular auto variables also - to 0 or any value before the actual value is input or calculated or returned by another function etc ?

When I initialize a static or global pointer variable to NULL (or it is done by default), what are the best practices of when and where to check the pointer value before using it or de-referencing it to modify  the dereferenced variable ? Should I stop checking the pointer in the functions that are called by other functions and by that time, the pointer cannot have stayed NULL, even if it were initially NULL ?

What about those pointers that can potentially get corrupted ? How should I check those ? Should I always check the value of the pointer and live with the small amount of extra code in every function that uses the pointer variable - just to make sure any abnormal event did not cause the pointer value (i.e. the address that it points to) to get corrupted ?

For auto pointers within a function, is there anything other than - checking the pointer variable to not be NULL once before the first use and then no need to check it in the rest of the function ?

Comment: Your last paragraphe is puzzling. Local variables (or auto variables as you call them) are not initialized upon function entry, they contain garbage. You __must__ initialize them prior to using them. Period.

Comment: Define variables when you can initialize them.  If the variable will be assigned/initialized by being passed via pointer to a function, there's no need to initialize it before passing.  (`int i; if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1) { … }` — there's no need to initialize `i`.)